# Ranorex form element coming as null when spying swing window

Tags: c#, swing, xpath, ranorex

I have a popUp container, inside which I have a DefaultComboBoxModel. The model contains a JComboBox which has a list of Machine name.

When I just spy the JComboBox, it shows the xPath as `/form[@title='MachinePage']/container[@type='JPanel']//combobox[@name='MachinePopup']`

But when I spy a Machine from the ComboBox i get the xPath as `/form//container/list[@name='ComboBox.list']/listitem[@text='Ferrari']`

I dont get the form name here. Can anyone say why?

Comment: Can you still find the listitem 'Ferrari' if you modify the second XPath to insert [@title='MachinePage'] between form and // ? Sometimes Ranorex Spy needs a little help to create the optimal XPath...

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the (IMHO annoying) features of Ranorex. You'll never really know what will be part of the XPath that Ranorex generates.

This is caused by the `StepCostReduce` model that Ranorex applies in order to simplify XPaths. Luckily you can change it in the options:

[image: Ranorex XPath generation mode]

I do not have a full overview yet on what the impact is. When set to `Simple`, it will record many properties. This will probably result in a performance decrease, because querying all the values from the application will take some time. IMHO such a performance decrease is still preferable over tests that do not work or break easily.

If you understand Ranorex internals (I do not yet), you might also change the options for the `StepCostReduce` model and optimize according to your needs:

[image: Ranorex XPath build options]

Example of a button in SAP:

[image: Ranorex before/after comparison]